# Two types of user accounts that need to become one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Currently we are using devise for our users to login into our site, but we have two devise models. One for users and one for landlords. Right now our users are created atomically when a user opens our iOS app for the first time. When a user goes to create a listing they create another user account called landlords. I need a way to make those into one but keep the current functionality for our iOS app and add the ability to sign in via facebook. Any thoughts or input on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when a User makes a Landlord account, pass in the user_id, and then transfer all fields to the Landlord user type, then delete the user, or something like that. Alternatively you could set a boolean determining if the user is a landlord.

For facebook, use omniauthable with Devise. The example is for facebook https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview